# What language is used to program nano quadrotor behaviour?

Tags: robotics

Just watched this [fascinating and terrifying video](http://www.pcworld.com/article/249150/nano_quadrotors_swarm_in_formation_will_take_over_earth_with_grace.html). I'm curious what programming language / paradigm is used to control these beasties?

Comment: Terrifying Swarms of Beasties That Will Take Over The Earth are usually programmed in the most terrifying language of all: VBA!!! :P

Comment: http://kmelrobotics.com/ Ask them.

Comment: IBM System/370 Assembler!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term I see most often for the algorithms is [decentralized adaptive control](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=decentralized+adaptive+control).  There are some [papers](https://alliance.seas.upenn.edu/~swarms/wiki/index.php?n=Main.Papers) available from the group that designed it, although their site looks like it hasn't been updated in a few years.

According to [this electronic design article](http://electronicdesign.com/article/embedded/Cooperation-Leads-To-Smarter-Robots/3.aspx), the quadrotors are running [Robot Operating System (ROS)](http://www.ros.org/wiki/), which has support for both python and C++.  I couldn't find which language is used on this particular project.

Comment: A bit more about ROS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROS_(Robot_Operating_System)